# plot.new has not been called yet when making tiff-file

Tags: r, plot, spline

I am trying to add text (the nonlinearity p-value) to a plot of a restricted cubic spline regression model. When I try this in R studio it works fine, however the moment I try to add code to save it as a .tiff file, I get the following:

> Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) :
>     plot.new has not been called yet

This is my code (for a restricted cubic spline regression model for the association between determinant labtsh and endpoint ecard with 3 knots):

```
spline <- cph(Surv(ecard_f,ecard_n)~rcs(labtsh,3)+age+gender+ckdepi+smoking, data=smart)

tiff(file ="H:/documents/test.tiff", width = 1000, height =1000, units = "px", res = 145) 

plot(Predict(spline,labtsh,fun=exp), pch = 20, las = 1,
    conf.int=T, 
    main="Relationship TSH and myocardial infarction", 
    xlab="TSH (mIU/L)", 
    ylab="Hazard Ratio")

my.p <- anova(spline)[2,3]  ##this is the value I want to add in the plot

rp = vector('expression',2)
rp[1] = substitute(expression(Non-linearity))[2]
rp[2] = substitute(expression(italic(p)-value == MYVALUE), 
               list(MYVALUE = format(my.p, digits = 3)))[2]
legend('topleft', legend = rp, bty = 'n')

dev.off()
```

Like I said, if I take away the call to make it a .tiff-file and the `dev.off()` line, the code works fine.

I have searched multiple answers for similar questions here on stackoverflow, but the answers don't seem to help me.

Comment: Are you closing the graph that appears in the popup before calling dev.off()?

Comment: No, I've been careful not to do that. The plot in the popup was open the whole time!

Comment: I'm not sure, but can you try to add this command (or something like this) before you call the plot command above: `plot(0,type='n',axes=FALSE,ann=FALSE)`

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks!